# Scala: avoiding redundant type parameters

Tags: scala, type-parameter

Suppose I have an abstract class Bar that takes a type parameter:

```
abstract class Bar[A] { def get: A }
```

and I have a function that wants to instantiate some `Bar` objects, call their `get` methods and return the results:

```
def foo[A, B <: Bar[A]]: Seq[A]
```

It seems a little verbose to have to provide A as a separate type parameter, since it's implicit in `B`.  What I would really like is to say

```
def foo[B <: Bar[A]]: Seq[A]
```

but that doesn't compile.  Is there a way to make `foo` more compact?

Comment: Not only it is not "implicit", that declaration won't even help infer `A`. What I mean by "not implicit" is that you could have written `[B <: Bar[String]]` -- in which case you'd be referring to an existing type, not a parameter. How would you deal with such ambiguity?

Comment: I guess you could define a way of telling the compiler "this is a type parameter", something like `def foo[B <: Bar[~A]]: Seq[A]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Daniel said in the comment.

Perhaps using an abstract type member will help reduce the verbosity.

```
abstract class Bar { 
  type A
  def get: A 
} 

def foo[B <: Bar]: Seq[B#A]
def baz[B <: Bar](b: B): Seq[B#A]
def taz[B <: Bar](b: B): Seq[b.A]
```

Comment: That's pretty cool.  It didn't get it to work for me in this particular case, because of the way I was using reflection to instantiate objects, but it's always good to learn some new syntax.

Comment: @KenjiMatsuoka, abstract type members have somewhat different semantics than type parameters. In general they are interchangeable but not always.